# Edit text in Android Studio using XML and Java

Tags: android-studio

How can I place the eye icon for a password inside the edit text in Android Studio and how will I change the icon's height and width?

I tried using <android:drawableRight="@drawable/view">, but the image's size is too large and I'm not able to adjust its height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways

**Method 1**

Create a new XML drawable file name as **password_visibility_item_selector.xml** for the password eye icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/baseline_visibility_off_24" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/baseline_visibility_24" />

</selector>
```

Below is referred XML code for EditText & Password here you can change the size of the eye icon for password hide & visible

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextLayoutPass"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="20" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivShowHide"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/password_visibility_item_selector"
        android:state_selected="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextLayoutPass"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextLayoutPass"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editTextLayoutPass" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now You can now show and hide the password programmatically

```
    binding.ivShowHide.setOnClickListener {
        if (binding.ivShowHide.isSelected) {
            binding.edtPassword.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
            binding.edtPassword.setSelection(binding.edtPassword.length())
            binding.ivShowHide.isSelected = false

        } else {
            binding.edtPassword.transformationMethod = HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()
            binding.edtPassword.setSelection(binding.edtPassword.length())
            binding.ivShowHide.isSelected = true
        }
    }
```

**Method 2**

By this method, you can use the TextInputEditText default option for the password eye icon to show & hide the password.

Create a new XML drawable file name as **password_icon_selector.xml** for the password eye icon.

Here is XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextLayoutPassword"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/purple"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility_item_selector"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="20" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can also set a custom icon

```
app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility_item_selector"
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```